# Android Studio Generate Signed apk not working

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

What is happening with me is that in case of one of my project in Android studio, when I try to generated signed apk by going to  Build--> Generate Signed APk, I provide keystore and password. Then it takes long time to build Grade and at the end no apk file is generated. Just nothing happens.

- This happens only in one particular project. I can generate signed apks for other projects in my workspace.

Any hint that what can be the problem? At this point, I even don't know that where can be mistake?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: For clarification. have you upgraded your android studio recently?

Comment: Yes I upgraded Android studio. Issue was that it was giving me error related with string translations missing. I resolved them by providing translations of strings.

Comment: I found that my problem was that my Keystore path was wrong. Android Studio didn't tell me anything was wrong with it, it just silently didn't bother doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the APK is not generating because some PNG are not consistent for an AndroidStudio stand point.

For instance you can have such error (but the console is not showing it)

Error:Execution failed for task ':myApp:mergeReleaseResources'.

> Crunching Cruncher btn_back.png failed, see logs

It happened for me last week with Android Studio 1.3

So you can process your PNG as follow (using imagemagick)

find . -name "*.png" -print -exec convert "{}" "{}" ";"

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who may still run across this, my issue was that I had a typo in the key store password that I was using. Rather than giving any indication that the password was incorrect, Android Studio was just failing silently.